# MySQL throwing "Operating system error number 22" -- what is going on?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to create a new InnoDB table using DATA DIRECTORY command to put the .ibd file on a different drive. I am on CentOS, using Percona MySQL 5.6.27, and I have innodb_file_per_table enabled. Below is the command I'm running:

```
CREATE TABLE `xxx` (
 `log_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `campaign_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `subscriber_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `message` text,
 `processed` enum('yes','no') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'no',
 `retries` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `max_retries` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '3',
 `email_message_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `status` char(15) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'success',
 `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`log_id`),
 KEY `fk_campaign_delivery_log_archive_list_subscriber1_idx` (`subscriber_id`),
 KEY `fk_campaign_delivery_log_archive_campaign1_idx` (`campaign_id`),
 KEY `sub_proc_status` (`subscriber_id`,`processed`,`status`),
 KEY `email_message_id` (`email_message_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=150095504 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 DATA DIRECTORY='/mysql/archive/'
```

This throws a `#1030 - Got error -1 from storage engine` in phpmyadmin. Looking at MySQL error log, this is the error:

```
InnoDB: Error: Write to file ./abc/xxx.isl failed at offset 0.
InnoDB: 62 bytes should have been written, only 0 were written.
InnoDB: Operating system error number 22.
InnoDB: Check that your OS and file system support files of this size.
InnoDB: Check also that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded.
InnoDB: Error number 22 means 'Invalid argument'.
InnoDB: Some operating system error numbers are described at
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/operating-system-error-codes.html
```

I tested the `CREATE TABLE` code without `DATA DIRECTORY` and it works fine.

I've done `chown` on `/mysql/archive` and set it to mysql:mysql, so mysql has access to the folder. I also confirmed that `/mysql/archive` has plenty of empty space.

I tried editing `/etc/my.cnf` and setting `innodb_use_native_aio = 0` but that doesn't help.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are you setting `AUTO_INCREMENT` so high?

Comment: Not sure. That is just what the `SHOW CREATE TABLE` output. I'm trying to copy an existing table structure. Is that my problem?

Comment: Changing `AUTO_INCREMENT` doesn't help

Comment: Did you `check that the disk is not full or a disk quota exceeded`? Did you follow the link provided?

Comment: Yes, I checked. The disk is not full and the quota is not exceeded. Yes, I followed the link provided, it doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what was wrong. Apparently there is a bug in innoDB 5.6.26+ as described at https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=79200. I had to remove `innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT`